The configuration provided for ServiceStack deployment on an IIS server is causing significant slowdowns for the site
Why does the inclusion of the following configuration in the web.config file lead to substantial performance degradation for the website deployed with ServiceStack on an IIS server?
<handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="false" />
    <!-- <remove name="WebDAV" /> -->
</handlers>

How to configure the web.config file for a ServiceStack project or modify the above configuration to improve the site's speed?

Every request, including accessing APIs and third-party resources, takes over 20 seconds to load.
